# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages (Laravel installer 4.2.7)

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I run the below command in cmd it gives me this error.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myProject
```

I also have checked some extensions in php.ini like fileinfo, openssl etc.
For more details see the below picture.

[image]

Comment: The error says you don't have the `fileinfo` extension enabled

Comment: Did you run `php --ini` as shown to determine if the extension is loaded?

Comment: php --ini show this: C:\xampp\htdocs\Dev>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php-8.0.6\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: I already enabled fileinfo extension but it still show this error I don't know why.